# Can't load all my functions via requirejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

I have to include some js functions via requirejs, these functions need google api, so:

1. I included the google api link in `<head>`(it is placed at the last) .
2. Included the js functions in js file.
3. I call these functions in my phtml.

Errors:

> - uncaught exception: InvalidValueError: buildMap is not a function
> - TypeError: markers is undefined

The files :

**app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/module_index_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" layout="1column">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="head.additional">
            <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\block" name="googlemaps.api" template="Vendor_Module::googlemap-script.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**googlemap-script.phtml**

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=123456&libraries=places&callback=buildMap" async defer></script>
```

**app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            module: 'Vendor_module/js/go',
        }
    }
};
```

**app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/go.js**

```
define(['jquery', 'domReady!'], function($, doc) {
    'use strict';

    function setZoom(map, markers)
    {

        var boundbox = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            for ( var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ )
            {
              boundbox.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i]['latitude'], markers[i]['longitude']));
            }
            map.setCenter(boundbox.getCenter());
            map.fitBounds(boundbox);

    }

    function buildMap()
    {
        var options = {
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP //SATELLITE,ROADMAP,HYBRID
            };
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), options);
                //var marker = new google.maps.Marker({map: map, position:latlng});
                $.each(jsStoreTab, function(index,valeur)
                {//each paire de données
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(valeur['latitude']),parseFloat(valeur['longitude']));
                        cm_createMarker(latlng, 'html', index+1,valeur);
                    }, index * 200);


                        })


                        if(jsStoreTab.length>1) setZoom(map,jsStoreTab);
                        else
                        {
                            var centreCarte = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(jsStoreTab[0]['latitude']),parseFloat(jsStoreTab[0]['longitude']));
                            map.setZoom(13);
                            map.setCenter(centreCarte);

                        }
                        directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
                        directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
                        initAutocomplete();
                        $.each(filtersTab, function(idxFilterGroup,filterGroup){
                            $('#filters').append('<fieldset class="'+idxFilterGroup+'"><legend>'+filterGroup.name+'<a title="Informations sur les '+filterGroup.name+'" href="'+filterGroup.url+'" target="_blank"></a></legend></fieldset>');

                            $.each(filterGroup.datas, function(idxFilter,filter){
                                $('#filters fieldset.'+idxFilterGroup).append('<input filter_group="'+idxFilterGroup+'" type="checkbox" id="'+filter.replace(/ /g ,'_')+'" onclick="markerFilter()" value="'+filter+'"><label for="'+filter.replace(/ /g ,'_')+'">'+filter+'</label>');
                            });

                        });
    }

    function markerFilter()
    {

        if($('#filters fieldset input:checked').length==0)
        {
            $.each(allMarkers,function(idx,marker){marker.setVisible(true);});
            return true;
        }
        $.each(allMarkers,function(idx,marker){
            marker.setVisible(false);
            $.each($('#filters fieldset input'),function(idxInp,inp){
                if($(inp).prop("checked"))
                {
                    $.each($('#filters fieldset input'),function(idxInp,inp){
                        if($(inp).prop("checked"))
                        {
        console.log('CHECKED',$(inp).attr('id'),$(inp).attr('filter_group'), marker.datas[$(inp).attr('filter_group')] );
                            if(typeof marker.datas[$(inp).attr('filter_group')]!== 'undefined' && marker.datas[$(inp).attr('filter_group')].indexOf($(inp).val())!=-1 ) marker.setVisible(true);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    }

    function attachInfoWindow(marker, num)
    {
          marker.addListener('click', function() {
            if (infowindow) { infowindow.close();}
            infowindow= new google.maps.InfoWindow({
              content: $('#listeStations li.store[data-markerid='+num+']').html()
            });
            infowindow.open(marker.get('map'), marker);
            $('#list li.store').removeClass('list-focus');
            $('#list li.store[data-markerid='+num+']').addClass('list-focus');
          });

    }

    function initAutocomplete()
    {
        var options = {
            types: ['geocode'],
            componentRestrictions: {country: "fr"}
        };
        autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
        (document.getElementById('select-ville')),options);
        autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
    }

    function fillInAddress()
    {
        // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
            var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
            maPosition.latitude=place.geometry.location.lat();
            maPosition.longitude=place.geometry.location.lng();

            var maPos = new google.maps.LatLng(place.geometry.location.lat(),place.geometry.location.lng());
            if(allMarkers.length>jsStoreTab.length) allMarkers[allMarkers.length-1].setMap(null);//suppression de la dernière position
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                      position: maPos,
                      map: map,
                      title: "Vous êtes ici",
                      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
                  });
            allMarkers.push(marker);
            var minDist=999999999;
            var bestPos=0;
            $.each(jsStoreTab, function(index,valeur)
            {
                var dist=calculdist(maPosition,valeur);
                if(dist<minDist)
                {
                    minDist=dist;
                    bestPos=valeur;
                }
            })
            var markerBounds=[bestPos,{'latitude':maPosition.latitude,'longitude':maPosition.longitude,'name':'Vous êtes ici'}];

            setZoom(map, markerBounds);
            routeInitialize();
            calcRoute(maPosition,bestPos);

            //calculdist(parseFloat($('#autocompGoogleForm #latitude').val()),parseFloat($('#autocompGoogleForm #longitude').val()));
            return false;
    }

        // Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
    function geolocate()
    {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            var geolocation = {
                lat: position.coords.latitude,
                lng: position.coords.longitude
            };
            var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
                center: geolocation,
                radius: position.coords.accuracy
            });
            autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
            });
        }
    }
    function deg2rad(deg)
    {
        return deg * (Math.PI/180)
    }

    function calculdist(pos1,pos2)
    {
        var R = 6371; // Radius of the earth in km
        var dLat = deg2rad(pos1.latitude-pos2.latitude);  // deg2rad below
        var dLon = deg2rad(pos1.longitude-pos2.longitude );
        var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) + Math.cos(deg2rad(pos2.latitude)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(pos1.latitude)) * Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2);
        var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
        var d = R * c; // Distance in km
        return d;
     }

    function routeInitialize()
    {
        directionsDisplay.setMap(null);
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
    }

    function calcRoute(start,end)
    {
      var request = {
        origin: new google.maps.LatLng(start.latitude, start.longitude),
        destination: new google.maps.LatLng(end.latitude, end.longitude),
        travelMode: 'DRIVING',
        drivingOptions: {
            departureTime: new Date(Date.now() ),  // + Nfor the time N milliseconds from now.
            trafficModel: 'optimistic'
        },
        unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC // en kms

      };
      directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
        if (status == 'OK') {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
            //https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#DirectionsResults
            var distance = 0;
            var delay = 0;
            var legs = result.routes[0].legs;
            for(var i=0; i<legs.length; ++i) {
                distance += legs[i].distance.value;
                delay += legs[i].duration.value;
            }


            var days= parseInt(delay / (3600*24));
            var restDays=delay%(3600*24);
            var hours=parseInt(restDays/3600);
            var restHours=restDays%3600;
            var min=parseInt(restHours/60);

            var delayPrint='';
            if(days>0) delayPrint+=days+' jours ';
            if(hours>0) delayPrint+=hours+' h ';
            if(min>0) delayPrint+=min+' min';


            $('#distance').text(Math.round(distance/1000)+' kms');
            $('#duree').text(delayPrint);

        }
      });

    }

    function stOver(num,id)
    {
        //console.log('stOver',num,id);
        //https://mapicons.mapsmarker.com/numbers-letters/numbers/?style=iphone&custom_color=23a605
            allMarkers[num].setIcon("https://www.oselia-beaute.com/media/storelocator/images/markers/black/number_"+id+".png");
    }

    function stOut(num,id)
    {

        //https://mapicons.mapsmarker.com/numbers-letters/numbers/?style=iphone&custom_color=23a605
            allMarkers[num].setIcon("https://www.oselia-beaute.com/media/storelocator/images/markers/yellow/number_"+id+".png");

    }

    function cm_createMarker(point, html, rank,tab)
    {
        //https://mapicons.mapsmarker.com/numbers-letters/numbers/?style=iphone&custom_color=23a605
        //console.log("https://www.oselia-beaute.com/media/storelocator/images/markers/green/number_';?>"+rank+".png");
              var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage("https://www.oselia-beaute.com/media/storelocator/images/markers/yellow/number_"+rank+".png",
                          new google.maps.Size(32, 37),
                          new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                          new google.maps.Point(10, 34));



              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  position: point,
                  map: map,
                  icon: image,
                  title: tab.name,
                  animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                  datas : tab
              });
              attachInfoWindow(marker,parseInt(rank));
              allMarkers.push(marker);
    }
    function logit() {
        console.log('hi');
    }

    //I return all the functions for the phtml
    return {
        setZoom         : setZoom,
        buildMap        : buildMap,
        markerFilter    : markerFilter,
        attachInfoWindow : attachInfoWindow,
        initAutocomplete : initAutocomplete,
        fillInAddress   : fillInAddress,
        geolocate       : geolocate,
        deg2rad         : deg2rad,
        calculdist      : calculdist,
        routeInitialize : routeInitialize,
        calcRoute       : calcRoute,
        stOver          : stOver,
        stOut           : stOut,
        cm_createMarker : cm_createMarker,
        logit : logit
    }

});
```

**file.phtml**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
require(['jquery', 'domReady!', 'module'], function($, doc, module) {
    'use strict';
    module.setZoom();
    module.buildMap();
    module.markerFilter();
    module.attachInfoWindow();
    module.initAutocomplete();
    module.fillInAddress();
    module.geolocate();
    module.deg2rad();
    module.calculdist();
    module.routeInitialize();
    module.calcRoute();
    module.stOver();
    module.stOut();
    module.cm_createMarker();
    module.logit();
});
```

**info** : I think that he can't load the google api, (I saw it in source code of  the page module) this is all the first functions breaks my last test function `module.logit();`, like this I can't see my console.log of `logit()`, but if I place it before all the functions in phtml, my `console.log` message 'hi' appear.

Comment: You seem to be using some kind of framework; I'm not familiar with the phtml file extension. You might want to [edit] your question and add the tag for the framework you are using.

Comment: yes, it is a Magento one but the phtml file it is not the problem, it's like html and we can php on it

Comment: Well, without knowing that, how would one be able to recreate your problem? If you want help, help the people trying to help you :). See [ask] and how to create a [mcve].

Comment: You are right..

Comment: I think `requirejs` use `module` keyword for some internal stuff, so, my recommendation is to change in your config `module` for something else and update your code accordingly.